# Can't make Share works

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

i'm using the Intense template to make a UWP application, the problem is that i can't make the Share works, cause i don't know how to navigate from the app.xaml.cs with this template.

```
protected override async void OnShareTargetActivated(ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        ShareOperation shareOperation = args.ShareOperation;
        //Can't make any navigation
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get Microsoft source code to retrieve `Frame` object

```
    private Frame CreateRootFrame()
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            rootFrame = new Frame();
            // Place the frame in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        return rootFrame;
    }
```

and use like you want

```
    protected override void OnShareTargetActivated(ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        var rootFrame = CreateRootFrame();
        // your page and share operation as navigation parameters
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(ShareTargetPage), args.ShareOperation);
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
```

[Microsoft Sample Project](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ShareTarget)

Comment: I keep getting "System.Exception", if i try to just end the share with "shareOperation.ReportCompleted()" it crashes too.